# ¿Cómo reemplazar SlidingMenu o navigation drawer con un Activity o Fragment?

Tags: android

Es posible reemplazar el menu "SlidingMenu" con un `Activity` con otras opciones, tengo lo siguiente:

[image: Como tengo actualmente el proyecto]

Voy a tener una opcion mas que diga configuracion: En esta deseo mostrar varios opciones pero no necesito que me llene el `Fragment` de fondo, que todo se trabaje en el menu. Que termino como esto:

[image: El menu anterior es reemplazado por un Activity]

¿Mi dificultad es como llamar, que llamar, un `Activity`, un `Fragment` y como colocarlo encima del Menu?

```
if (oFragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, oFragment).commit();

         //update selected item and title, then close the drawer
         oDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
         oDrawerList.setSelection(position);
         setTitle(navMenuTitles[position - 1]);
         oDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(oDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error al crear el Fragment");

        Log.i("Fin", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        String Variable;

        Variable = "";

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Cerrando sesión !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();            

        Log.i("La variable", Variable);

        SharedPreferences preferencias=getSharedPreferences("SESION",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor=preferencias.edit();
        editor.putString("USUARIO", Variable.toString());
        editor.putString("VEHICULO_PREDETERMINADO", Variable.toString());
        editor.commit();    

        Log.i("Fin", Variable);
        finish();           
    }
```

Pero lo que estoy intentando reemplazar es el menu mismo, sin que se esconda, como en la segunda imagen.

Answer (score 1):

Tiene que ser un `fragmento` (No es opción cargar un `Activity`), al dar clic al elemento dentro del menú simplemente agrega el `Fragmento`

```
    public void selectItem(int position)
    {
         switch(position)
         {
              case POSICION_CONFIGRUACION:        
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
                         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();   
                         Fragment fragment = new FragmentConfiguracion();
                         fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                         fragmentTransaction.commit();
             break;
          }
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A donde detectas el identificador del menú, para así cargar el fragment dependiendo del elemento seleccionado, es donde tienes que detectar la acción y cargar la actividad settings, pero no tendrá el sliding menú, deberás añadir un botón tirar hacia atras, para volver a la zona de la app con el menú.